React Native: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app' when trying to run on Android studio
I have tried to run a existing react native cli machine 
i have installed all package and upgrade the Gradle version and upload the latest setup in local system
Recat Native Version - 0.73
NPM -verison 10.5.1
node -version 20.12.0

Can you post the is build.gradle line 142 ?
